# Writing to TXT file Freezes After Exceeding 630 Megabytes

Tags: python, windows, ntfs

I am gathering big amount of data from network and writing it to a TXT file for  analyzing later. I write to file like following :

```
from time import sleep
import json
with open("big_txt.txt", 'w') as opened_file:
    while True:
        data = {"data" : "Some Important Data"}
        json.dump(data, opened_file)
        opened_file.write("\n")
        sleep(0.001)
```

However, when the file size exceeds 630 Megabytes, (I tried this 3 times) writing to file freezes without showing no error. I search the web about maximum file size in NTFS ( I am using NTFS ) and found the following in Microsoft knowledge base article : [Microsoft NTFS Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc781134(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
Which states the following :
NTFS Size Limits

**Maximum file size**
Architecturally: 16 exabytes minus 1 KB (264 bytes minus 1 KB)
Implementation: 16 terabytes minus 64 KB (244 bytes minus 64 KB)

**Maximum volume size**
Architecturally: 264 clusters minus 1 cluster
Implementation: 256 terabytes minus 64 KB ( 232 clusters minus 1 cluster)

I think this makes the problem very interesting because the file size is not exceeding the stated limit. However you can try in your computer (assuming you are using NTFS, and have enough time to fill txt) and you will get the same results. What is the reason behind this and what is the best way to overcome this problem? Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: I do not have NTFS, but I can tell you will all certainty that 630MB is nothing to write home about. Very trivial size nowadays. I suggest you look closer at what exactly is happening in your script.

Comment: If this is indeed reproducible, it probably has nothing with Python to do. What happens if you use a simple batch file? Are you sure it's not just because you run out of space?

Comment: @SergeyA I will check my script again but, there is no error I am getting while running and program is nearly as simple as the code I added to question

Comment: @tripleee I checked my utility values in all my runs and it appeared I have %60 CPU usage and %50 RAM usage while TXT size near 628MB, after 630 its usage remains the same but writing to file stops.